# Getting "Non-continuous variable supplied error" when setting y limits

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am getting a small problem using ggplot2 geom_line graph.

When I apply `ylim`, the graph goes empty. In a default mode, the ggplot clutters up the y-axis with all the values, but I want to increase the reference limits to little big gaps, i.e from 17.3,17.5,17.7 to 17-18 with the graph intact. I am using `ylim(c(15,30))`, the limit is increased but graph disappears.

I tried using `scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(15,30))`:

> [Error: Non-continuous variable supplied to scale_y_continuous]

and `scale_y_discrete(breaks=c(15,30))`

[Whole y bar disappears]

[image]

After limits:
[image]

DataFrame:

```
>head(meltedB)
             Mouse     Type       days weight
    1      21-H807  control 2011-09-23   27,0
    2      21-H808  control 2011-09-23   27,8
    3 21-H809/J125 knockout 2011-09-23   29,1
    4      21-H810  control 2011-09-23   27,2
    5      21-H811  control 2011-09-23   18,2
    6      21-H812  control 2011-09-23   18,8
```

Command used :

```
ggplot(na.omit(meltedB),aes(factor(days),weight,group=Mouse)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color=Mouse),size=2) + 
    facet_grid(Type~.)
```

** For someone who is struggling with plotting of NA values, use na.omit on your dataframe, they wont be plotted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two big hints that R has provided you to diagnose this problem. The first is the really ugly decision about the y axis tick labeling. The second is the explicit error message that says you passed a "non-continuous" variable to `scale_y_continuous`.

Your y variable is stored as a factor (or possibly a character). Type `str(meltedB)` at the console to confirm.

The problem is most likely the commas. You'll need to go back to when you read in the data and change the `dec` argument to `read.table`, which is set to a period by default.

Comment: Thanks Joran, you are right, it was stored as an factor.
Using 'dec' solved the problem, though the y breaks are not continuous.
I used scale_y_discrete(breaks=seq(15,40,by=1)) to get breaks from 15 to 40 with a distance of 1 but they are separated haphazardly within these limits.
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ylim() and (scale_y_discrete()) cuts out data that overstep these new boundaries because it automaticly also sets limits() to the same.

There are two workarounds

- use scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(15,30), limits=range(dataset))
- use coord_cartesian(ylim=c(15,30)) instead # (which only "zoomes" in on the data)